# FileZilla Server installed on Google Compute Engine can't not be accessed from outside

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, ftp, google-compute-engine, filezilla

I have a Windows Server 2022 datacenter compute engine (i.e. a Windows VM) on Google Cloud Platform (GCP). I installed FileZilla Server 1.2.0 on it. When I try to connect to the ftp Server from another computer via internet, it results in timeout error and fails to retrieve directory listing. I have done the exactly same setup in an other non-google cloud vm and it works fine there. So I think I would have to take GCP into consideration in the current issue. Let's refer to the GCP one as environment "A" and the non-google one as "B" later.

Upon connecting via internet to A, the ftp server generated the following log:

```
2022-07-28T06:24:41.712Z >> [FTP Session 1 ooo.ooo.ooo.ooo] USER testuser
2022-07-28T06:24:41.712Z << [FTP Session 1 ooo.ooo.ooo.ooo] 331 Please, specify the password.
2022-07-28T06:24:41.721Z >> [FTP Session 1 ooo.ooo.ooo.ooo] PASS ****
2022-07-28T06:24:41.806Z << [FTP Session 1 ooo.ooo.ooo.ooo testuser] 230 Login successful.
2022-07-28T06:24:41.816Z >> [FTP Session 1 ooo.ooo.ooo.ooo testuser] SYST
2022-07-28T06:24:41.816Z << [FTP Session 1 ooo.ooo.ooo.ooo testuser] 215 UNIX emulated by FileZilla.
2022-07-28T06:24:41.838Z >> [FTP Session 1 ooo.ooo.ooo.ooo testuser] FEAT
2022-07-28T06:24:41.838Z << [FTP Session 1 ooo.ooo.ooo.ooo testuser] 211-Features:
2022-07-28T06:24:41.838Z << [FTP Session 1 ooo.ooo.ooo.ooo testuser] 211 End
2022-07-28T06:24:41.848Z >> [FTP Session 1 ooo.ooo.ooo.ooo testuser] PWD
2022-07-28T06:24:41.848Z << [FTP Session 1 ooo.ooo.ooo.ooo testuser] 257 "/" is current directory.
2022-07-28T06:24:41.869Z >> [FTP Session 1 ooo.ooo.ooo.ooo testuser] TYPE I
2022-07-28T06:24:41.869Z << [FTP Session 1 ooo.ooo.ooo.ooo testuser] 200 Type set to I
2022-07-28T06:24:41.880Z >> [FTP Session 1 ooo.ooo.ooo.ooo testuser] PASV
2022-07-28T06:24:41.880Z << [FTP Session 1 ooo.ooo.ooo.ooo testuser] 227 Entering Passive Mode (10,140,0,4,233,55)
2022-07-28T06:24:41.900Z >> [FTP Session 1 ooo.ooo.ooo.ooo testuser] MLSD
2022-07-28T06:24:41.900Z << [FTP Session 1 ooo.ooo.ooo.ooo testuser] 150 About to start data transfer.
```

where ooo.ooo.ooo.ooo is the public IP of the client. This connection eventually failed. At the same time the messages shown in client side (using FileZilla Client) are:

```
Status: Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Plain FTP is insecure. Please switch to FTP over TLS.
Status: Logged in
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Status: Server sent passive reply with unroutable address. Using server address instead.
Command: MLSD
Response: 150 About to start data transfer.
Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
Status: Disconnected from server
```

where xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is the public IP of the ftp server. From the log we can see that I have successfully logged in, so we can rest assured that this is not a firewall issue. I searched for this problem online all day but can not find a solution yet. The closest one I got is [this one](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/803334/Failed-to-retrieve-directory-listing-filezilla-con) which was found from [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/g/gce-discussion/c/dnNQwdfMBUw?pli=1), but both of them are quite old and some key links are not reachable now. From them I learned about the fact that the problem might be this line of the server log:

```
2022-07-28T06:24:41.880Z << [FTP Session 1 ooo.ooo.ooo.ooo testuser] 227 Entering Passive Mode (10,140,0,4,233,55)
```

where it entered passive mode with "private IP", and this explains why in client side we see

```
Status: Server sent passive reply with unroutable address. Using server address instead.
```

As the client is connecting via internet, the ip address 10.140.0.4 is unroutable. As I mentioned above I have an environment B where things work fine, and I have observed that the server side log says it entered passive mode (###,###,###,###,...,...) where #'s is the "public IP address" of server B! So the thing is, I do not know in A what I shall do to fix this problem. And is it a problem of GCP Compute Engine or FileZilla Server itself?

Could you please help provide me with some cure? Thank you very much!

Comment: You need to configure FileZilla with the public IP address so that the PASV command returns the correct IP address.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thank you very much for pointing out that I should tell FileZilla the public IP address explicitly. I get things work now. I have spent some time finding clues in the VM itself (since as I mentioned that environment B works normally) and turned out it was a waste of time. Glad that you show me the right way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to answer to my question by myself. Hope this is a responsible act to those who came by and stopped to think, and also a help to those who is/will encounter the same problem.
The key is, if you have both a public and a internal IP addresses on a computer which runs FileZilla Server in passive mode, for clients to access the service via internet one has to tell FileZilla Server the public IP address. I mentioned above that I have a working environment B, turns out it has no internal IP address installed, so there is no confusion. It had been an easy experience in B so I had now idea that I will have to do some extra settings in A. This can be found in the [official documentation](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Network_Configuration#Passive_mode_2). Specifically, as illustrated in the figure below, the public address should be put down in the input.
[image]